# Delete using Periodic Iterate not working

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm using this query to delete a lot of nodes, and it works fine in 4.0.0 but using 4.1.1 it doesn't seem to work

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('
MATCH (s:Thing{id:$thingId})
  CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(s, {}) YIELD node
  RETURN node',
'DETACH DELETE node',
{batchSize:2000, iterateList:true, parallel:false, params: { thingId: $idOfThingToDelete}}) YIELD total, batches, errorMessages
RETURN total
```

It errors with the following

> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.periodic.iterate`: Caused by:
> org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: Node 78063 not found

And then further down in the log, we get this

> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.periodic.iterate`: Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: NOT PART OF CHAIN!
> RelationshipTraversalCursor[id=64250, open state with:
> denseNode=false, next=64250, mode=regular, underlying
> record=Relationship[64250,used=true,source=86327,target=86330,type=7,sPrev=64238,sNext=-1,tCount=1,tNext=-1,prop=478773,secondaryUnitId=-1,!sFirst,
> tFirst]]

I can see the node with id 78063 and it looks fine, so I don't understand why it's saying it can't find it.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

**Update**

This is the second query I tried, which uses distinct, but it still gives me a *Node 12345 not found* error

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    'MATCH (t:Thing{id:$thingId})
    CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(s, {}) YIELD node
    RETURN DISTINCT node',
    'DETACH DELETE n',
    {batchSize:2000, iterateList:true, parallel:false, params: { thingId: $idOfThingToDelete}}) YIELD total, batches, errorMessages
RETURN total
```

Comment: After migrating from Neo4j 3.5 to 4.2.6 (both Enterprise Edition) we also have the phenomenon `java.lang.IllegalStateException: NOT PART OF CHAIN!` in unchanged code. Also with us it is to be narrowed down to `apoc.path.subgraphNodes` in an `apoc.periodic.iterate` fragment, a `DISTINCT` or heap size extension unfortunately does not help.

Answer (score 0):

The `apoc.path.subgraphNodes` procedure can return the same node multiple times, so it should use `RETURN DISTINCT node` to ensure that each node is only returned once.

For instance:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  'MATCH (s:Thing{id:$thingId})
   CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(s, {}) YIELD node
   RETURN DISTINCT node',
  'DETACH DELETE node',
  {batchSize:2000, iterateList:true, parallel:false,
   params: {thingId: $idOfThingToDelete}}) YIELD total, batches, errorMessages
RETURN total
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this reply! We put this change in and it seems to work perfectly for us on 4.0.0, but while it seems to reduce memory usage (possibly) on 4.1.1, it does still give us the "Node not found" error. We are returning the node Id distinct rather than the node itself (RETURN DISTINCT ID(node) AS nodeId). Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: I will as soon as I can (hopefully in the next hour or two), thanks again.

Comment: Same problem unfortunately, using this query (below)

Comment: Actually, posted the new query as an update to my original question for formatting reasons

Comment: Increasing the batch size helps but with larger amounts of data we just have to keep upping the value otherwise I just keep running into the same issue